# IE7's z-index bug, a complex case

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a popup window with form fields and dynamic tooltips. In every browser the tips show up fine, but in IE6/7 they show up below the form fields. Classic bug, but I can't find a solution that works.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEnBA.png), Firefox 5 on top and IE7 on bottom.

Without delving into the code too much, the form has the following nested structure:

```
div.pp (position: absolute; z-index: 200)
  -> div#le, div#ri
    -> label (position: relative)
      -> span.tip (position: absolute; z-index: 300)
```

Note that span.tip's are dynamically generated and injected into the labels, making them siblings with the inputs.

**EDIT: [Here is a demo](http://budreviews.com/zindex/).**

Comment: Please post a URL or include a simplified HTML snippet reproducing the problem-- with some sample HTML to play with it will be much easier find a solution.

Comment: what is the parent container of the right column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was IE re-creating z-indexes for children of relatively positioned elements, making it impossible to set z-indexes for different tool tips relative to one another.

The solution lay in simplifying the page for IE. I nixed the relative positioning on the labels, absolutely positioned the tooltips relative to div.pp, and used javascript to correctly position the anonymous tooltips and dynamically set z-indexes. When the z-indexes for the tips were *lower* than those for their parent (div.pp) the tips displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, in IE<8 the z-index of your relatively positioned parent element must be higher than the z-index of the relatively positioned span element you want to overlay.

In your case, I'd try to give the relatively positioned `span` a z-index. But without the whole HTML context it is hard to tell.

**EDIT**: After looking at the demo I'd try giving the relatively positioned labels on the left a `z-index` higher than the ones on the right:

```
.pp .le label{z-index: 10}
.pp .ri label{z-index: 5}
```

Comment: That's the just of what I read, but here the layer ordering is a bit more complicated. Added a demo, hopefully it helps illustrate the bug.